# Pervasive SQL Database to live visual interface like Sharepoint

Tags: pervasive-sql

We currently use an accounting software (Sage 50) hosted on a local machine. It has many shortcomings and I want to build custom datasets/tables and display information to my organization. I am able to access the Pervasive Database our software runs off of in Razor SQL.

My question is a black box questions, how can I spit out this dataset to a internal site like Sharepoint (or even a shared Excel file) so everyone is my organization can view these reports? Pervasive ODBC connection is 32 bit only, so Excel cannot open the data source. Is there a way to setup a query to "copy/paste" the pervasive database into a 64 bit DB like MYSQL or MSSQL?

I did try to build out PowerBI Desktop reports which "worked" but refreshing the data set takes a very long time (like 3 mins). I tried to publish the data set to sharepoint but it cannot get auto refresh to work and everyone apparently needs Power Bi premium to view these reports. It has become a headache.

Comment: What version of Pervasive PSQL are you using?  There has been a 32 and 64 bit ODBC driver since PSQL V11.

Comment: 32 Bit I believe. I followed these directions from the software company. At the bottom it says "Note: Currently ODBC connections will not work with 64-bit database programs." https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=12693&

Comment: Are you using PSQL V10 or older?  You can see the version of the Pervasive Control Center as a guide or use BUTIL -VER from a command line to get a version.

Comment: @mirtheil so apparently Sage 50 deploys a slimmed down version of pervasive. Tried to add Pervasive Control Center but the file does not exist. Anyways it says it's "Pervasive PSQL v11"

Comment: Since you've got PSQL v11, you should be able to download the 64 bit PSQL v11 client (https://www.actian.com/data-management/zen-embedded-database/psqlv11/) even though it's outdated and possibly unsupported. Once you've downloaded and installed, you should be able to create a 64 bit ODBC connection to the engine / database.